# Como deixar campo com valores em negrito

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

**Situação** Tenho uma tabela feita em html chamada Pagamentos e nela tenho uma coluna chamada valores, quero deixar os campos com valores em negrito.

**Problema:** Tem colaborador que teve valor para ser pago e outros não.
Como deixo apenas os campos com valores maiores do que 0 em negrito?

**Cenário Ideal:**  Deixar apenas os campos com valores maior do que 0 em negrito.

**HTML:**

```
  <table id="data-table-default" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th class="col-xs-1 text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salario1)
                            </th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1 text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salario2)
                            </th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1 text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salario3)
                            </th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.Salario1)
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.Salario2)
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.Salario3)
                                </td>


                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

Comment: Você usou `<b>` e não deu certo?

Comment: Sim porém se eu colocar b ou strong em qualquer linha ele pinta de negrito a ideia é só quando tiver uma verificação maior do que 0 ai ele deixa em negrito caso contrario ele nao deixa em negrito.

Não sei colocar essa parte em pratica rs!

Comment: E você não sabe usar um `if`?

Comment: @Maniero Opa por exemplo seria algo do tipo.

if(MeuModel > 0)
{
   <b>Conteudo</b>
}Else{conteudo}

Ficaria dessa forma correto? Porem teria que fazer linha por linha, teria como fazer em uma verificação só?

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso, agora você já está perguntando outra coisa. Até tem como fazer isso em um laço, mas precisaria usar um truque já que você não tem um *array*, então teria que criar um com os nomes dos campos. Também funcionaria com uma função que abstraia isso, teria que chamar 3 vezes, mas não teria toda repetição de código e não precisaria criar um *array*. Dá até pra criar uma nova *tag*  que faça isso de forma abstraída. Mas aí já estamos falando de outro problema diferente da pergunta.

Comment: @Maniero cara ajudou bastante, muito obrigado mesmo consegui fazer aqui.
Obrigado pelas informações meu amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thiago Correa, no caso a condição tem que ser restrita ao campo, não teria como fazer uma verificação única para percorrer na tabela, pois a condição é exclusiva do "campo".
Tem que ser feito um `IF` para cada campo.
Através do javascript (jQuery), você conseguiria resolver, mas não está no escopo da pergunta.